# Unity3D: Rigidbody2D not colliding with BoxCollider2D

Tags: unity

In Unity3D (Version 5.3.1f1 Personal) I have a scene with a sprite with a Rigidbody2D and some sprites with a BoxCollider2D. The BoxColliders **don't** have the `Is Trigger` enabled and the RigidBody is **not** `Kinematic`, but they are not colliding. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The RigidBody gameobject also requires a Collider in order for collisions to work

Answer (score 1):

[Rigidbody2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.html) is a component that gives the GameObject physics properties like gravity, mass, drag etc in a 2D environment.

[BoxCollider2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/BoxCollider2D.html) is component that gives the GameObject a box shaped collision detector with certain surface properties in a 2D environment.

When you simulate physics in your game like object falling with gravitational acceleration, stop moving when in contact with another collision detector, having force applied etc you need both `BoxCollider2D` and `Rigidbody2D`.

In some case like non moving obstacles where we usually don't want physics simulation but just collision detection or trigger detection, `Rigidbody2D` can be ignored. But one of the collides must have `Rigidbody2D` in it for collision or trigger detection.

There is also [layer based collision detection](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html) if you want work with layers of collision detection or ignorance.

Comment: The collision now works, but the player tilts when it touches a wall (see this GIF: http://i.imgur.com/llVGNPy.gif)

Comment: try freezing Z rotation on the Rigidbody

Comment: mark as right answer if things work for you.